# Homebrew GDAL installation ECW or MrSID

Tags: gdal, jpeg-2000, homebrew

I have experimented with installing gdal 1.9.1 via homebrew.  It works wonderfully.  Unfortunately, their is no real JP2000 support.  I realize that JP2000 is supported by OpenJp2000, but that implementation is buggy to say the least.

Using the KyangChaos gdal installer I am able to add ECW support quite easily.  Has anyone been able to get ECW support for a homebrew installation of GDAL?  The default in the forumla is to build '--without-ecw'.  I am brand new to homebrew and not quite sure how to even begin to gain some better JP2k support.

Comment: Are you on Mountain Lion? I'm asking because after adding ECW plugin from Kyngchaos I still see no JP2000 support in gdalinfo --formats?