# Alternatives to ArcGIS Image Server Extension to serve Mosaic Dataset?

Tags: imagery, image-service, arcgis-image-server

I am wondering if anyone has any resources for alternatives to ESRI's [ArcGIS Image Extension for Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/serverimage)?

We are looking to serve JP2000 images that have been consolidated using the Mosaic Dataset Method in ArcGIS.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thread [Homebrew GDAL installation ECW or MrSID](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31182/homebrew-gdal-installation-ecw-or-mrsid) suggests no good open source support for the JP2000 format, otherwise loading data into PostGIS and serving through GeoServer would be a great alternative - the PostGIS raster storage method would be a great way to access tiles of imagery through a database table structure... GeoServer I'm sure (correct me if I'm wrong anyone) would be fine for serving up that imagery... again, you'd have to consider a different format.

Comment: I am fine with translating the imagery out of jp2000...actually prefer it. but its native format is jp2000. what would be the best practice then for PostGIS/Geoserver in terms of format?

Comment: I think when you load your rasters into PostGIS they become the native PostGIS raster type... rather than say storing JPEG or TIF in PostGIS, you load those formats into PostGIS and the pixels are stored in a raster data type column... the tricky part might be converting from JP2000 into PostGIS, which might require converting first to TIF or something similar...

Comment: It's been some years since the initial answer and updates. Any new developments? I know https://stacspec.org/ aims to create a "common language" for spatial data. But it does not actually store the data. So it will probably interface to tools like ImageServer and PostGIS/Geoserver. The question remains - are there other tools available?